# Why didn't the other dragons help Igneel in defeating Acnologia?

Tags: fairy-tail

In the Tartaros arc of *Fairy Tail*, when Igneel appeared to fight or defeat Acnologia, why didn't the other dragons help?

Answer (score 0):

Fear acnologia was so dangerous that even if many dragons joined most would die Igneel was just extremely courageous